# Fast weighted intersection algorithm for CFG and FSA with self loops but no other circles?

Tags: fl.formal-languages, automata-theory

We all know that arbitrary CFG and FSA can be intersected using the Bar-Hillel Construction, whose time complexity is unfortunately too expensive. On the other hand, there are efficient algorithms that intersects intersect CFGs with lattices (i.e. acyclic FSAs). If an FSA is much like a lattice, except that all circles it can possibly have are self loops, is there any efficient algorithm for intersecting such an FSA with a CFG?

Comment: Wouldn't an acyclic FSA accept a finite language? In fact, in [this](http://acl.ldc.upenn.edu/J/J00/J00-1002.pdf) paper, an acyclic FSA is called a _dictionary_. In any case, it would be helpful to give a reference for the intersection algorithm of CFLs/CFGs with acyclic FSAs.

Comment: Just a remark on the way the question is stated: the Bar-Hillel algorithm is in $O(|Q|^3)$ for unweighted automata with state space $Q$.